# Semi-automatic annotation tool like '@nnotate'

Tags: nlp, corpora, syntax-trees

Is there an annotation tool for linguistic structure that compares to [@nnotate](http://www.coli.uni-saarland.de/projects/sfb378/negra-corpus/annotate.html)? One of the major features of annotate is the annotation is semi-automatic, i.e., it uses a language model to make annotation suggestions to the annotator.
Unfortunately it is slightly outdated as it depends on Tcl/Tk 8.0.

Is there an annotation tool with a comparable feature set?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Out of curiosity, what is Tcl/Tk 8.0?

Comment: You could try [WebAnno](http://code.google.com/p/webanno/). But it's still in Beta at the moment.

Comment: Thanks robert. Is it correct that that WebAnno does not have an interface to a tagger, or a parser? - Or I am missing something?